# Creating Custom SQL Translations/Expressions in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

In the near future, our C#/MVC Web application is to be internationalized. We can get 80% of the way there using resource files and the provided component model attributes on our view models. However, it's a bit more tricky with database driven content...specifically, our lookup tables. We've come up with a design that actually works quite well using XML columns in our tables. For instance, a color table would have this data in the Translation column:

```
<root>
    <en name="Blue" description="The description" />
    <es name="Azul" description="La descripción" />
    <fr name="Bleu" description="La description" />
</root>
```

We can query and even sort by the appropriate language using a query like this:

```
SELECT
    ColorId, 
    Translation.value('(/root/en/@name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    Translation.value('(/root/en/@description)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM OurLookupTable
ORDER BY Translation.value('(/root/en/@name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

Unfortunately, there is no way right now for us to query the database using lambda expressions like we used to:

```
MyContext.Colors.Select(c => new {
    c.ColorId,
    c.Name,
    c.Description
}).OrderBy(c => c.Name);
```

Is it possible to be able to create custom expressions so we'd be able to do something like this?

```
MyContext.Colors.Select(c => new {
    c.ColorId,
    Name = c.Translation.GetName("en"),
    Description = c.Translation.GetDescription("en")
}).OrderBy(c => c.Translation.GetName("en"));
```

What is the topic I need to be looking for? I'm guessing it's a combination of expression trees and sql translations. Any additional insight or links to tutorial resources would be appreciated.